# Reading and storing settings in a QGIS project with QgsProject.instance()

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to save full path to project settings and read it out and put it in the LineEdit function.

Save the path is working but to read it out and handle it with LineEdit doesn't?

Here is what I have done so far:

```
def select_output_file(self):
    filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self.dlg, "Selecteer output file ","", '*.ext')
    QgsProject.instance().writeEntry("mytools", "last_path", (str(filename)))
    self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(filename)
```

This works for me. When I read it out in the python console of QGIS I get this.

```
last_path = QgsProject.instance().readEntry("mytools", "last_path", "Output file")[0]
print last_path    
D:/users/xxxxxx/downloads/filename.ext
```

So the path is correct, I think. But now I want to read it back like this next code:

```
last_path = QgsProject.instance().readEntry("mytools", "last_path", "Get last path")[0]
self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(last_path)
```

And here is where I don't get the path in the LineEdit field?

When I use this next code it works.

```
last_path = "C:/user/xxxx/"    
self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(last_path)
```

And also this line works in python console.

```
last_path = QgsProject.instance().readEntry("mytools", "last_path", "Get last path")[0]
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What do you get if you use `print last_path` after `last_path = QgsProject.instance().readEntry("mytools", "last_path", "Get last path")[0]`? Also which QGIS version and platform are you using? And are you aware in your code snippet, you typed `gsProject` instead of `QgsProject`? :)

Comment: Hello Joseph, Sorry for the mistype in the code i correct it. 
I use Windows 10 and Qgis version 2.18.13

When i put a "print last_path" i get the full path from the project. So that's why i don't understand the code is not working.

Comment: Perhaps try using `self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(str(last_path))`

Comment: Is your path contain special caracter ? Did you try with the simplest as possible ? Did you try with unicode decoder string ? Like this u'your Windows path'